# PHP: get values from node by name (problems with namespaces)

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I received these xml from external services:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href=(...)?>
<pos:Document xmlns:pos=(...) xmlns:str=(...) xmlns:xsi=(...) xsi:schemaLocation=(...)>
  <pos:DescribeDocument>
    (...)
  </pos:DescribeDocument>
  <pos:UPP>
    (...)
  </pos:UPP>
  <ds:Signature Id="ID-9326" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
    <ds:SignedInfo Id="ID-9325" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:pos="adress" xmlns:str="adress" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        (...)
    </ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:Object>
        <xades:QualifyingProperties Id="ID-9337a6d1" Target="#ID-932668c0-d4f9-11e3-bb2d-001a645ad128" xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#">
            <xades:SignedProperties Id="ID-9337a6d0" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:pos="adress" xmlns:str="adress" xmlns:xades="adress" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                    <xades:SigningTime>sometime</xades:SigningTime>
                    <xades:SigningCertificate>
                        <xades:Cert>
                            <xades:CertDigest>
                                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="adress"/>
                                <ds:DigestValue>someValue</ds:DigestValue>
                            </xades:CertDigest>
                            <xades:IssuerSerial>
                                <ds:X509IssuerName>CNsomeValue</ds:X509IssuerName>
                                <ds:X509SerialNumber>SerialsomeValue</ds:X509SerialNumber>
                            </xades:IssuerSerial>
                        </xades:Cert>
                    </xades:SigningCertificate>
                    <xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                        <xades:SignaturePolicyImplied/>
                    </xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
                </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
                <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
                    <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#ID-93257e60">

                        <xades:Description>NEEDVALUE</xades:Description>

                    </xades:DataObjectFormat>
                </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
            </xades:SignedProperties>
        </xades:QualifyingProperties>
    </ds:Object>
  </ds:Signature>
</pos:Document>
```

It's have a few namespace. And I have to get value in value.
I wrote a some code but nothing works:

```
$xmlFileContent = file_get_contents($pathToXML);
$dom = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlFileContent, LIBXML_COMPACT);

$namespaces = $dom->getNamespaces(true);
foreach ($namespaces as $key => $namespace) {
    $dom->registerXPathNamespace($key, $namespace);
}
$matches = $dom->xpath('//xades:Description'); //no success
```

and

```
$doms = new DOMDocument;
$doms->loadXML($path);
foreach($doms->getElementsByTagNameNS($namespaces['xades'],'*') as $element){
    echo 'local name: ', $element->localName, ', prefix: ', $element->prefix, "\n";          //no success
}
```

Can you help me to get to these node (xades:Description)?

PS:
i used it too (but no success):

```
$result1 = $dom->xpath('/Dokument/ds:Signature/ds:Object/xades:QualifyingProperties/xades:SignedProperties/xades:SignedDataObjectProperties/xades:DataObjectFormat/xades:Description');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is possible *workaround* by modifying your XPath to ignore namespaces, just in case you can't find *proper solution* :

```
$result = $dom->xpath('//*[local-name() = "Description"]');
```

Answer (score 2):

You removed the namespace definitions from your XML. If you see an attribute like 'xmlns:xades' the actual namespace is the value of that attribute. It defines an alias/prefix for that namespace in the current context. Most of the time URLs are used as namespace identifiers (because it avoids potential conflicts). But a value like `urn:somestring` is valid.

You need to register a prefix for the namespace on the DOMXpath object, too. This prefix does not need to be identical to the one in the document. Look at it this way:

DOMDocument resolves a node name from `prefix:Description` to `{namespace-uri}:Description`.

DOMXpath resolves the node names in the Xpath expressions the same way using its own definition. For example `//prefix:Description` to `//{namespace-uri}:Description`. Then it compares the resolved names.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($dom);
$xpath->registerNamespace('x', 'urn:xades');
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(//x:Description)'));
```

Output: https://eval.in/181304

```
string(9) "NEEDVALUE"
```